# ZCML allowed_attributes corresponding method in five.grok

Tags: plone, zope, grok

Is there a way to mark methods traversable in `grok.CodeView` classes, like you can do with Zope 3 BrowserView and `allowed_attributes` ZCML configuration directive?

I found docs about `grok.traversable()` but it looks like such method does not exist in five grok package.

Comment: Moreover, grokcore.traverser depends on grokcore.view > 2 while dexterity's KGS currently pins grokcore.view to 1.3.15.

Comment: Any help about this??

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not possible as there has not been answers for 3 years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible: "the render() method is the only traversable in grok.codeView classes"

as stated in: https://developer.plone.org/templates_css_and_javascripts/javascript.html

Comment: Haha. I wrote that line myself long time ago. I am not sure how much truth it holds, so I would rather have a direct reference to Grok source code. In any Grok is pretty much dead project by now.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: :D, your line might be true, at least `view/w/details/render`, as suggested in the [docs](http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.app.dexterity/custom-views.html#simple-views), doesn't work with Dexterities, which were created TTW (model-driven).